# Как скопировать список в другую коллекцию сайтов sharepoint сохраняя историю версий?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

На Sharepoint 2010 есть большой список (более 10к записей) с прикреплёнными файлами. Как правильно сделать такой же в новом семействе сайтов? Сейчас делаю через экспорт-импорт:

```
        SPList list = new SPSite("http://localhost/").OpenWeb("sourceSite").Lists["Список"];
        SPExportObject exportObject = new SPExportObject();
        exportObject.Id = list.ID;
        exportObject.Type = SPDeploymentObjectType.List;

        SPExportSettings exportSettings = new SPExportSettings();
        exportSettings.SiteUrl = "http://localhost/destSite";
        exportSettings.ExportMethod = SPExportMethodType.ExportAll;
        exportSettings.FileLocation = @"c:\export";
        exportSettings.FileCompression = false;
        exportSettings.ExportObjects.Add(exportObject);

        SPExport export = new SPExport(exportSettings);
        export.Run();

        SPImportSettings importSettings = new SPImportSettings();
        importSettings.SiteUrl = "http://localhost/destSite";
        importSettings.WebUrl = "http://localhost/destSite";
        importSettings.FileLocation = @"c:\export";
        importSettings.FileCompression = false;
        importSettings.RetainObjectIdentity = false;

        SPImport import = new SPImport(importSettings);
        import.Run();
```

Но это решение не сохраняет историю изменений объектов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

включить все версии:

```
exportSettings.IncludeVersions = SPIncludeVersions.All;
```

Comment: Спасибо, версии появились. Но я ожидал, что автор и даты изменения будут такими же, как в оригинале. Возможно ли это?